# This block must only be used with the source from which it was created

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm using a TPL Dataflow with this initial network:

```
(a)CustomSource => (b)TransformBlock
```

When a message arrives in b, b creates a new transform block with a filter and append it to itself (it does not that for each message).

The network becomes like that:

```
(a)CustomSource => (b)TransformBlock => (c with linkto filter)TransformBlock
```

After a few runs the network becomes like that:

```
(a)CustomSource => (b)TransformBlock 
    => (c with linkto filter)TransformBlock
    => (c with another linkto filter)TransformBlock
    => (c with another linkto filter)TransformBlock
```

This works nice, and is the only solution i found to get a default action for a "switch" block.

But when the source is completed by calling customSource.Complete(), it throws an exception :

> ArgumentException: This block must only be used with the source from which it was created
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.DataflowBlock.FilteredLinkPropagator`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.ITargetBlock<T>.OfferMessage(DataflowMessageHeader messageHeader, T messageValue, ISourceBlock`1 source, Boolean consumeToAccept)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.SourceCore`1.OfferMessageToTarget(DataflowMessageHeader header, TOutput message, ITargetBlock`1 target, Boolean& messageWasAccepted)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.SourceCore`1.OfferToTargets(ITargetBlock`1 linkToTarget)
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.Internal.SourceCore`1.OfferMessagesLoopCore()

Comment: Could you post a short code that reproduces the problem? My guess is that you're trying to offer messages from `CustomSource` directly to the `LinkTo` filter, but I have no idea how would you do that.

Comment: I think i found the problem. One of the "c" TransformBlock was faulted. When a block is faulted it does not unlink automatically from the network. Adding a completion task to unlink the block seems to fix this problem.

Comment: btw, the "c" TransformBlock faults because it is linked to one child block with a filter, but the filter always returned false. It seems TPL Dataflow does not discard the message, but faults the block. I'm using the version included in .NET 4.5 beta.

Answer (score 1):

One of the "c" TransformBlock was faulted. When a block is faulted it does not unlink automatically from the network. Adding a completion task to unlink the block seems to fix this problem.